# Navbar goes out when I add animate on scroll feature

Tags: javascript, css, animate-on-scroll

I am trying to implement animate on scroll in my site [here](https://demo.justinechacko.in/) using [AOS](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos)

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
   AOS.init({
       duration: 1200,
   });
</script>
```

and used like

```
<div data-aos="fade-up">
```

But my navbar goes out in mobile version. See [this](https://i.ibb.co/0qFsD4L/Screenshot-20190531-175817.png)
And Some content not loading [here](https://demo.justinechacko.in/chips/2019/05/24/file13.html), see [this](https://i.ibb.co/NWs5CSv/Screenshot-20190531-175837.png) image.

Comment: if you are using `fade-left` or `fade-right` with position absolute it creates problem in mobile screen devices and all content are loading !

Comment: Navbar issue fixed by changing `fade-left` to `fade-up`. Still the content is loading only after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a simple overflow-x: hidden

```
<div class="row text-center no-gutters" style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-right">...</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-up">...</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-left">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes changing fade-left to fade-up fixed the problem, navbar is not working properly when fade-left is used